# SSL Certificate for SingleStore managed instance on Laravel Vapor Environment

Tags: laravel, singlestore, laravel-vapor

First time setting up SingleStore with Laravel Vapor on AWS.

I am stuck as to where / how to point the PDO connection to use the SSL / pem from SingleStore. I have the pem deploying to the app root.

My DB config is:

```
    'singlestore' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3307'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

And in the Vapor environment I have tried:

```
 MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA=singlestore_bundel.pem
 MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA=~/singlestore_bundel.pem
 MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA=~/public/singlestore_bundel.pem
```

How do I point the PDO connection to the pem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Jack Ellis helped me out on how he does it with Fathom.

In the database config file, for SingleStore:

```
'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') && env('APP_ENV') !== 'testing' && env('APP_ENV') !== 'local' ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => resource_path('singlestore/singlestore_bundle.pem'),
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => (env('IS_HEROKU') == 'yes')
 ]) : [],
```