# Laravel + MySQL + SSL-Mode - SQLSTATE[HY000] [3159]

Tags: mysql, laravel, ssl, linode

On Linode I've setup a MySQL Database Cluster and an Ubuntu server with Apache and PHP 8.1.

When I SSH onto the Ubuntu server I'm able to connect to the cluster:

`mysql --host=lin-xxx-mysql-primary-private.servers.linodedb.net --user=xxx --password --ssl-mode=required`

However, when I run `php artisan migrate` I get the following error:

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [3159] Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON. (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = xxxrch  and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712
    708▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    709▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    710▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    711▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 712▕             throw new QueryException(
    713▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    714▕             );
    715▕         }
    716▕     }

      +33 vendor frames 
  34  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I have not setup any certificates/pem files which other answers reference, but it still works from the mysqlclient.

What would I add to my `.env` to `config\database.php` to get this working?

Comment: I'm still working on it, but this has moved me forward https://www.linode.com/community/questions/22942/mysql-database-cluster-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I addressed this:

1. Download the cert from the Linode dashboard.
2. Place it in `resources\certificates`

In `config/database.php` I added:

```
'sslmode' => env('DB_SSLMODE', 'prefer'),
'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') && env('APP_ENV') !== 'testing' && env('APP_ENV') !== 'local' ? array_filter([
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => resource_path('certificates/certificate.crt'),
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => true,
]) : [],
```

One thing that's important to note is that this will not work for `phpunit` tests.

This answer was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70468831/1343140

Comment: **What will be for RDS cluster**
General error: 3159 Database Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON